# Giving a text label to int value (SQL) depending on whether it's NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

(MySQL) As a part of a slightly more complex query, I want to return a label. The label value depends on whether a specific field has a value or is null.

I'm expecting something like this:

```
SELECT 
   ....
   (CASE managerID
        WHEN IS NULL THEN "SelfManaged"
        WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN "Managed" 
   END CASE) as Type
   ....
FROM
   ....
```

I don't think the COALESCE function is appropriate, as I don't really want the value - just my label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply

```
CASE WHEN managerID IS NULL THEN 'SelfManaged' ELSE 'Managed' END  AS Type
```

Comment: Why not indeed. Thanks - can't see the wood for the trees sometimes.